# 2008 R2 Remote desktop services login issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I have installed and deployed a remote desktop server in a hyper-v clustered env.

My question is - Is it normal to be able to view an active session by right clicking on the host VM and connecting (without entering password etc) I think I may have setup TS incorrectly.

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question, and the situation that you're outlining is unclear. Please take a minute to re-read this and use the edit button to fix it up a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the server "console".  Just as you can go to a physical server and view what's on the screen, Hyper-V manager allows the same thing.  My guess is the user is choosing to log into the console.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, how to I prevent the user from accessing the console, as I cannot login a the administrator and make a change if people are logging in etc. Ok I've just had a think about it and I am going to apply a GP for this purpose.